# Template "ASP.NET Core with Angular" not working out of the box in VS Codespace

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, codespaces

I can't get to run the template "ASP.NET Core with Angular" in Visual Studio Codespace (Browser Version).

What I try:

1. On https://online.visualstudio.com/environments, I create a Basic
   Linux Codespace named 'mpb'. The new workspace opens in the browser.
2. With Ctrl+¨ I open the terminal
3. I type `dotnet new angular -au Individual` to create the template "ASP.NET Core with
   Angular"
4. I hit F5
5. I select Node.js

An error appears: " '${file}' can not be resolved. Please open an editor. "

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you select node.js? It is an ASP.NET Core app, you should use .NET Core as the environment. After you selected .NET Core, you should have a section named ".NET Core Launch (web)" in your launch.json file in the .vscode folder.